# validate multiple select boxes selecting only one

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have multiple select boxes that the user has to select at least one

here is the code

```
    <select name="c_hotels[hotels][2][single_room]" id="c_hotels_2_single_room" class="c_hotels_select_room" style="width: 70px;" onchange="calculate_hotels_prices();">
    <select name="c_hotels[hotels][2][double_room]" id="c_hotels_2_double_room" class="c_hotels_select_room" style="width: 70px;" onchange="calculate_hotels_prices();">


    <select name="c_hotels[hotels][3][single_room]" id="c_hotels_3_single_room" class="c_hotels_select_room" style="width: 70px;" onchange="calculate_hotels_prices();">
    <select name="c_hotels[hotels][3][double_room]" id="c_hotels_3_double_room" class="c_hotels_select_room" style="width: 70px;" onchange="calculate_hotels_prices();">
```

For each hotel user can select single or double room

I want to validate so the user must select at least one of the checkboxes

i have create a method

```
$.validator.addMethod("sel`enter code here`ect_hotel", function(value) {
    var result=false;


    $( ".c_hotels_select_room" ).each(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");                      
        var value=$("#"+id+" option:selected").val();
        if(value)
        {
           var result=true;
        }
    })

    return result;
},"message here);
```

and add dynamically the rule

```
$(".c_hotels_select_room").rules("add", { select_hotel:true});
```

The rule is working but the problem is that it places the message next to the first select box

I have add to the html

```
<label style="display:none" for="c_hotels_select_room" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```

so display this message in the place i want but its not working and a assume that its not mach the field name with the label for.

Can anyone help me place the message (i am trying to avoid use errorPlacement)

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `errorPlacement`?  Don't be scared of the customization options made available to you.   How else do you expect to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have not explained where you want to place the error messages, but the following code is flawed...

```
$(".c_hotels_select_room").rules("add", { select_hotel:true});
```

As per how the jQuery Validation plugin works, your line of code above will only assign the `.rule()` method to the ***first matched element*** in your jQuery selector.

If you want to assign the `.rule()` method to *all* elements matched by your selector, you **must** wrap it inside of a jQuery `.each()`...

```
$(".c_hotels_select_room").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", { select_hotel:true});
});
```

---

**EDIT**:

Documentation for the `.rules()` method: http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

for `.rules()`:

> *"... Returns the validations rules for the **FIRST selected element**."*

for `.rules('add')`:

> *"... Adds the specified rules and returns all rules for the **FIRST matched element**."*

for `.rules('remove')`:

> *"... Removes the specified rules and returns all rules for the **FIRST matched element**."*

Comment: i thought that because the selector is class will assign all available elements. I will investigate it

Comment: @ntan, yes, the selector targets a group of elements, however, the jQuery Validate plugin will only take the ***first matched element*** of that selector.  You **must** use a jQuery `.each()` when selectors target more than one element (when using the jQuery Validate plugin).  This is also true for all other jQuery Validate methods.  See my edits and the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var n= 0;
    jQuery("select").each(function() {
         n = n+ this.value;              
    });
    if (n < 1) { //obviously do all the checking
      alert("Please select any value");
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?